Actions behind the non-normal copies of $V_4$ in $S_4$
The action by left multiplication of the (abstract) Klein's 4-group $V_4$ on itself gives rise to the normal copy of it in $S_4$, namely $\{(),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$.
What other faithful (intransitive) $V_4$-actions do give rise to the three (intransitive) non-normal copies of $V_4$ in $S_4$?

We can easily classify all actions of $V_4$ on a $4$-element set, so this is a finite computation. The subgroups of $V_4$ are the trivial subgroup, $V_4$ itself, and the $3$ cyclic subgroups of order $2$, so $V_4$ has exactly five isomorphism classes of transitive actions, namely

a fixed point,
three transitive actions of size $2$ corresponding to the cosets of the three cyclic subgroups, and
the regular action of $V_4$ on itself.

So a faithful intransitive action on $4$ elements must have the form $V_4/g \times V_4/h$ where $g, h$ are distinct and nonzero, and there are exactly $3$ pairs of distinct nonzero elements of $V_4$. The resulting subgroups of $S_4$ are conjugate and are given by e.g. $\{ e, (12), (34), (12)(34) \}$ and so forth, so they're in bijection with the set of ways to split $4$ elements into $2$ unordered pairs. You can visualize these as pairs of opposite edges on a tetrahedron.
